# Can't send a texture to a custom shader (ShaderPass/EffectComposer)

Tags: three.js, textures, fragment-shader

I'm currently playing with this great library, but I have some difficulties with the EffectComposer.

I can't send a texture to a postprocess shader introduced by a ShaderPass.

I think this is a bug... or I'm doing something stupid (needUpDate, warp,... ??)

(r54, W7, Nv9700mGT, FF 17.0.1 and Chrome 24.0.1312.52)

I used the "webgl_postprocessing.html" example to reproduce the phenomenon just by adding these shaders :

```
<script id="vertexShaderBasic" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec2 glTexCoord;

    void main() {
        glTexCoord = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
</script>

<script id="fragmentShaderBlender" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying vec2 glTexCoord;
    uniform sampler2D sprite1;
    uniform sampler2D previousRender;

    void main() {
        vec3 color = texture2D( previousRender, glTexCoord ).rgb;
        color += texture2D( sprite1, glTexCoord ).rgb;
        gl_FragColor.rgb = color;
        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
    }
</script>
```

this at the begining of the main script to be sure the sprite is loaded :

```
var composer2;
function start() {
    init();
    animate();
}
var sprite1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/sprite1.jpg", null, start );
```

this in the composer field, after :
composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );

```
composer2 = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

var uniforms1 = {
    sprite1: { type: "t", value: sprite1 }, // <- something wrong here
    previousRender: { type: "t", value: null }
};

var blenderShader = {
    uniforms: uniforms1,
    vertexShader: $( 'vertexShaderBasic' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: $( 'fragmentShaderBlender' ).textContent
};
// link with the previous render
blenderShader.uniforms.previousRender.value = composer.renderTarget2;
// the custom shader
var blenderPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( blenderShader );
blenderPass.renderToScreen = true;

composer2.addPass( blenderPass );
```

I also coment this, beacause it's not relevent any more  :

```
//effect.renderToScreen = true;
```

and I add this at the end :

```
composer2.render();
```

The link between the two passes work well, but the sprite never appear on the EffectComposer quad that cover the screen...

Thanks and sorry for my english.

**EDIT to recap :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - postprocessing</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                background-color: #000000;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/DotScreenShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/RGBShiftShader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>

        <script id="vertexShaderBasic" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

            varying vec2 glTexCoord;

            void main() {
                glTexCoord = uv;
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            }
        </script>


        <script id="fragmentShaderBlender" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

            varying vec2 glTexCoord;

            uniform sampler2D sprite1;
            uniform sampler2D previousRender;

            void main() {

                vec3 color = texture2D( previousRender, glTexCoord ).rgb;

                color += texture2D( sprite1, glTexCoord ).rgb;

                gl_FragColor.rgb = color;
                gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
            }
        </script>


        <script>

            var camera, scene, renderer, composer;
            var composer2;
            var object, light;

            function start() {
                init();
                animate();
            }

            var sprite1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/sprite1.jpg", null, start );
            //var sprite1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/sprite1.jpg", new THREE.UVMapping(), start ); // change anything

            function init() {

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.z = 400;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x000000, 1, 1000 );

                object = new THREE.Object3D();
                scene.add( object );

                var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 4, 4 );
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

                for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ) {

                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    mesh.position.set( Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5 ).normalize();
                    mesh.position.multiplyScalar( Math.random() * 400 );
                    mesh.rotation.set( Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 2 );
                    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = Math.random() * 50;
                    object.add( mesh );

                }

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                scene.add( light );

                // postprocessing

                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
                composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );

                /////////////////////////////////////
                /////////////////////////////////////

                composer2 = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

                var uniforms1 = {
                    sprite1: { type: "t", value: sprite1 },
                    previousRender: { type: "t", value: null }
                };

                //uniforms1.sprite1.value.wrapS = uniforms1.sprite1.value.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

                var blenderShader = {
                    uniforms: uniforms1,
                    vertexShader: $( 'vertexShaderBasic' ).textContent,
                    fragmentShader: $( 'fragmentShaderBlender' ).textContent
                };

                blenderShader.uniforms.previousRender.value = composer.renderTarget2;

                var blenderPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( blenderShader );
                blenderPass.renderToScreen = true;

                composer2.addPass( blenderPass );

                /////////////////////////////////////
                /////////////////////////////////////

                var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.DotScreenShader );
                effect.uniforms[ 'scale' ].value = 4;
                composer.addPass( effect );

                var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.RGBShiftShader );
                effect.uniforms[ 'amount' ].value = 0.0015;
                //effect.renderToScreen = true;
                composer.addPass( effect );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function $( id ) {
                return document.getElementById( id );
            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                var time = Date.now();

                object.rotation.x += 0.005;
                object.rotation.y += 0.01;

                composer.render();
                composer2.render();
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

What I want :

[Good](http://flic.kr/p/dM9g9V)

What I get :

[NotGood](http://flic.kr/p/dMeQdb)

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. My first shader pass gets a texture as input, and subsequent shader passes get as input the result of previous passes, but subsequent shader passes can't seem to get a second texture as input, they just get black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too, and found a workaround.

I debugged it to determine that the **texture ID** for the extra texture is different in the shader pass than expected, which is bad. If you look in the ShaderPass constructor, you'll see it **clones the uniforms**. That seems to be the cause. If I edit that code to restore the original texture object in the cloned uniforms, it works as expected. So that should work for you too.

I'm trying to get some kind of (proper) bug fix integrated into the actual release.

Comment: It was an exciting school project ! but I'm not any more in that code so I can't say if it works. It's great if it helps. I just dig up the result I had : http://nizik.olympe.in/potiron_R1_medium.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var sprite1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/sprite1.jpg", new THREE.UVMapping(), start );
```

three.js r.54